The user is not signing in to Google Play Games
I am trying to implement Google Play Games sign-in. However, the sign-in is not successful. Is there a problem with the code, or is there a problem with the configuration in the console? If it is the code, how can I correct it? If it is in the console, what should I do? I followed all instructions correctly, and the Application ID, the Fingerprint, and the Package name are all set correctly.
private void requestSignIn() {
    GamesSignInClient gamesSignInClient = PlayGames.getGamesSignInClient(this);

    gamesSignInClient.signIn().addOnCompleteListener(signInTask -> {
        if (signInTask.isSuccessful()) {
            Log.d("Logged", "signInTask.isSuccessful() == true");
            boolean isAuthenticated = signInTask.getResult().isAuthenticated();
            Log.d("Logged", "isAuthenticated: " + isAuthenticated);
            if (isAuthenticated) {
                Log.d("Logged", "It is logged");
                changeActivity = true;
                ActivitiesLogic.changeActivity(thisActivity, LanguageSelectionActivity.class, buttonSound);
            } else {
                Log.d("Logged", "signInTask.isSuccessful() == true but it is not logged");
                // Here you might want to prompt user to try again or explain the issue
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.login_failed, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } else {
            Exception exception = signInTask.getException();
            Log.e("Logged", "signInTask.isSuccessful() == false", exception);
            if (exception instanceof ApiException) {
                ApiException apiException = (ApiException) exception;
                int statusCode = apiException.getStatusCode();
                if (statusCode == CommonStatusCodes.CANCELED) {
                    Log.d("Logged", "User canceled the sign-in");
                } else {
                    Log.d("Logged", "It is not logged, error code: " + statusCode);
                }
            } else {
                Log.d("Logged", "It is not logged");
            }
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.login_failed, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}

When I execute the code above and press "Continue" in the Google Play Games modal, I get the following logs in logcat:

2024-07-30 18:41:02.616 21733-21733 Logged
com.aof.qof.beer                     D  Is not logged, prompting
sign-in 2024-07-30 18:41:11.693 21733-21733 Logged
com.aof.qof.beer                     D  signInTask.isSuccessful() ==
true 2024-07-30 18:41:11.693 21733-21733 Logged
com.aof.qof.beer                     D  isAuthenticated: false
2024-07-30 18:41:11.693 21733-21733 Logged
com.aof.qof.beer                     D  signInTask.isSuccessful() ==
true but it is not logged

build.gradle:
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.aof.qof.beer'
    compileSdk 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.aof.qof.beer"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 34
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-games-v2:20.1.2"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:33.1.2')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
}

PS: In https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/consent, the Publishing status is "Testing" and the user being used is in the Test users list. In OAuth rate limits section, it is like no requisition was made.
I did more tests and realized it is logging with the user created by the e-mail that is used in the console, but the other user that is in the tester list is not working. Should I be concerned about something or it will be working with all users when released? Why is it working only with the user who owns the app in the Play Store Console?
